# How to Check if a SYSTEM environment variable exists?

Tags: powershell

There is USER Environment Variables, and SYSTEM environment variables.

How can i make this condition check ONLY for SYSTEM env variable if it exists?

```
if (-not Test-Path 'env:VariableX ') { 

    "doesnt exist!"
}
```

this would not return anything if VariableX is defined as a USER variable. i want to ignore that and only focus on if its defined in SYSTEM env variables

Comment: the following will give you the env vars for the system >>> `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables('Machine')` <<<

Comment: @Lee_Dailey so i would use it like this: if (-not [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables('Machine'))

Comment: you can either test to see if the EnvVar is in the resulting list OR use the singular version of the method to check for a _named_ EnvVar. ///// take a look at what shows up after the `::` for that type, OR look at what you get from `[System.Environment] | Get-Member -Static` ...[*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey is Machine required? i am using my VariableX and it errors out: Cannot convert argument "target", with value: "VariableX", for "GetEnvironmentVariables" to type
"System.EnvironmentVariableTarget": "Cannot convert value "VariableX" to type "System.EnvironmentVariableTarget".
Error: "Unable to match the identifier name VariableX to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following
enumerator names and try again:
Process, User, Machine""

Comment: you need to tell it "machine" to get the environment for the system instead of "user" to get the user EnvVars. for instance, this >>> `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Comspec', 'Machine')` <<< gives me `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` as the returned value. if i replace `Compspec` with `Vtc` - i get nothing back - meaning it does not exist in the "machine" EnvVar list.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey gotcha. I didnt know this syntax lol

Comment: i recommend you take some time to play with what shows when you start `[system.` ... there are all sorts of interesting things there. [*grin*]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would work:

```bsh
if (-not [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('VariableX', 'Machine'))
{
    "doesnt exist!"
}
```

Comment: but thats only Environment, shouldnt it be [System.Environment] if i am looking JUST for system variables?

Comment: @Cataster - the `System` in that case is just the dotnet system namespace. it is the default, so it can be left out. the `Machine` parameter is what decides the context to use.

Comment: ahhh interesting. what about if i want to look just for USER variables?

Comment: @Cataster - then replace `Machine` with `User` ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey sweet. so Machine is System

Comment: @Cataster - yep, just as the error you listed earlier - the valid contexts are `Machine`, `User`, and `Process`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey they should have just called it System. why confuse people like that lol

Comment: @Cataster Well, those variables are stored under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` registry hive. Hence, the `Machine`, I guess.

Comment: @Cataster - as GeorgeChakhidze pointed out, the naming scheme has a different source. the real gotcha was using 'system' in the EnvVar nomenclature that users see. [*grin*]

Comment: oh that makes sense.